# How to create a Dynamic action form in the details page - PHP

Tags: php, forms, session

I explain my obstacle, I have a page with all the campaigns and of course to be able to go to view the detail page of the campaign I want to view, I wrote a code:

```
<?php echo "<a href='info_campagna.php?id_campagna_cliente={$row['id_campagna_cliente']}'>Dettagli</a><br>";?>
```

automatically, once you enter the campaign detail page, the result in my url is something like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/FINALE/info_campagna.php?id_campagna_cliente=4
```

to be able to pull out all the values ​​that I need through a while loop, I wrote this query:

```
$id = $_GET['id_campagna_cliente'];
$sql = "SELECT *    
        FROM store_locator
            INNER JOIN campagne_cliente ON store_locator.id = campagne_cliente.impianto_id_campagna
            INNER JOIN clienti ON clienti.cliente_id = campagne_cliente.cliente_id_campagna
            INNER JOIN store_locator_category
            INNER JOIN campagne ON campagne.id_campagna = campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente
        WHERE campagne_cliente.id_campagna_cliente ='$id'
        GROUP BY impianto_id_campagna"
```

now in my form, which regulates the start of a search, through an input, for all the other parts of the project I called the command action = name of the page where the form was present but obviously in this case the action can not be: example: `action = "pagename"` but it must be: `action = "pagename? id_campagna_cliente = 4"`

in this case, I voluntarily put the number because I glued the url of the page with that id.

I tried to call the action in the same way that I enter the detail page, that is:

```
action="pagename.php?id_campagna_cliente={$_GET['id_campagna_cliente']}"
```

and the result obtained obviously is bankruptcy:

```
pagename?id_campagna_cliente={$_GET[%27id_campagna_cliente%27]}
```

no longer seeing anything. How can I give the action command to my form so that it is dynamic for each detail page with a different id?

How to create a Dynamic action form in the details page  - PHP

further details, this is my form:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="info_campagna.php?id_campagna_cliente=<?php echo $_GET['id_campagna_cliente']; ?>"></form>
```

but unlike all the other pages, when I send them, I do not search for any fields

Comment: Have you tried `action="pagename.php?id_campagna_cliente=<?php echo $_GET['id_campagna_cliente']; ?>"`  ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly not work, now i add another code in my question